# Sign conversion when ANDing and comparing

Tags: c++, gcc, casting, unsigned-char

I have the following code:

```
const uint8_t HEADER_SIZE = 0x08;
std::vector<uint8_t> a, b;
uint8_t x;

/* populate 'a', 'b'. Set 'x' */

for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < HEADER_SIZE; ++i )
{
    // The if statement (specifically the AND): Conversion to 'unsigned int' from 'int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
    if ( x != ( a[i + HEADER_SIZE] & b[i] ) )
    {
         /* ... */
         break;
    }
}
```

I tried casting almost everything, and I cannot seem to figure out why a simple AND is causing this warning. Both variables are unsigned. Any ideas?

Comment: The value of an object of type `uint8_t` (assuming `uint8_t` exists, which is not required) will always fit unchanged in an `int`, so the warning is harmless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `uint8_t`'s get promoted to `int` before being `&`ed together. Then that `int` is being compared to `x`, which is still `uint8_t`. Same thing happens with `i + HEADER_SIZE`. Casting results back to `uint8_t` should get rid of the warning.

```
x != uint8_t(a[uint8_t(i + HEADER_SIZE)] & b[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `a[i + HEADER_SIZE]` and `b[i]` will be promoted to `int` as, although they are both unsigned types they are narrower types than `int`. All narrower integer types are promoted to `int` (if `int` can represent all of the values of the type being promoted) or `unsigned int` for all built in arithmetic operations.

Explicitly converting all operands to an `unsigned int` should silence the warning:

```
unsigned int a_dash = a[i + HEADER_+SIZE];
unsigned int b_dash = b[i];
unsigned int x_dash = x;
if (x_dash != (a_dash & b_dash))
{ // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the indexing, try:

```
_a = a[i + HEADER_SIZE];
_b = b[i];
if ( x != (_a & _b) )
```

You will see the problem is on the _a = ... line. This is because the adding of i and HEADER_SIZE is causing a promotion from uint8_t to int.